# Sed is replacing the start instead of appending to end

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I am trying to modify a CSV file to append to the lines the value `A`. My conditional regex is `,$` where `$` is the last character.

My `sed 's/,$/,A/'` does not return any changes.

However doing `sed 's/$/########/'` replaces the first N characters of each line with my replacement string.

Example:

```
user@HOST:/loc/yearly_files$ head merged19.csv
1900-01-01 09:00, 2084, DCNN, DLY3208, 1, 310, 1011, , , , , , , , 5, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 1.1, , 0, , ,   , , , , , , , , , , 1, , , , , , , , 1, , 1, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , D, , , , D, , D, , , , , 79, A, ,
1900-01-01 09:00, 3197, DCNN, DLY3208, 1, 449, 1001, , , , , , , , 4, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 4.7, , 4.3, , , , , , , , , , , , , 0, , , , , , , , 0, , 0, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , D, , , , B, , B, , , , , 93.6, A, ,
1900-01-01 09:00, 4813, DCNN, DLY3208, 1, 653, 1001, , , , , , , , 4, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 2.3, , 1.7, , , , , , , , , , , , , 0, , , , , , , , 0, , 0, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , D, , , , B, , B, , , , , 89.2, A, ,
1900-01-01 09:00, 4967, DCNN, DLY3208, 1, 687, 1001, , , , , , , , 8, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 3.2, , 2.8, , , , , , , , , , , , , 0, , , , , , , , 0, , 0, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , D, , , , B, , B, , , , , 93, A, ,
1900-01-01 09:00, 5399, DCNN, DLY3208, 1, 778, 1001, , , , , , , , 8, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 5.8, , 5.7, , , , , , , , , , , , , 0, , , , , , , , 0, , 0, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , D, , , , B, , B, , , , , 98.5, A, ,
1900-01-01 09:00, 6950, DCNN, DLY3208, 1, 1047, 1011, , , , , , , , 6, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 6.1, , 5.1, , , , , , , , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, , , , , , , , , , H, , , , B, , B, , , , , 84.8, A, ,
1900-01-01 09:00, 7384, DCNN, DLY3208, 1, 1136, 1001, , , , , , , , 4, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 2.3, , 1.7, , , , , , , , , , , , , 0, , , , , , , , 0, , 0, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , D, , , , B, , B, , , , , 89.2, A, ,
1900-01-01 21:00, 2084, DCNN, DLY3208, 1, 310, 1011, , , , , , , , 8, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , -.6, , -.6, , ,   , , , , , , , , , , 1, , , , , , , , 1, , 1, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , D, , , , D, , D, , , , , 99.3, A, ,
1900-01-01 21:00, 3197, DCNN, DLY3208, 1, 449, 1001, , , , , , , , 8, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 5.7, , 5.6, , , , , , , , , , , , , 0, , , , , , , , 0, , 0, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , D, , , , B, , B, , , , , 98.5, A, ,
1900-01-01 21:00, 4967, DCNN, DLY3208, 1, 687, 1001, , , , , , , , 8, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 5.3, , 4.9, , , , , , , , , , , , , 0, , , , , , , , 0, , 0, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , D, , , , B, , B, , , , , 93.6, A, ,
user@HOST:/loc/yearly_files$ head merged19.csv | sed "s/$/,NULL/"
,NULL01-01 09:00, 2084, DCNN, DLY3208, 1, 310, 1011, , , , , , , , 5, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 1.1, , 0, , ,   , , , , , , , , , , 1, , , , , , , , 1, , 1, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , D, , , , D, , D, , , , , 79, A, ,
,NULL01-01 09:00, 3197, DCNN, DLY3208, 1, 449, 1001, , , , , , , , 4, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 4.7, , 4.3, , , , , , , , , , , , , 0, , , , , , , , 0, , 0, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , D, , , , B, , B, , , , , 93.6, A, ,
,NULL01-01 09:00, 4813, DCNN, DLY3208, 1, 653, 1001, , , , , , , , 4, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 2.3, , 1.7, , , , , , , , , , , , , 0, , , , , , , , 0, , 0, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , D, , , , B, , B, , , , , 89.2, A, ,
,NULL01-01 09:00, 4967, DCNN, DLY3208, 1, 687, 1001, , , , , , , , 8, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 3.2, , 2.8, , , , , , , , , , , , , 0, , , , , , , , 0, , 0, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , D, , , , B, , B, , , , , 93, A, ,
,NULL01-01 09:00, 5399, DCNN, DLY3208, 1, 778, 1001, , , , , , , , 8, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 5.8, , 5.7, , , , , , , , , , , , , 0, , , , , , , , 0, , 0, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , D, , , , B, , B, , , , , 98.5, A, ,
,NULL01-01 09:00, 6950, DCNN, DLY3208, 1, 1047, 1011, , , , , , , , 6, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 6.1, , 5.1, , , , , , , , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, , , , , , , , , , H, , , , B, , B, , , , , 84.8, A, ,
,NULL01-01 09:00, 7384, DCNN, DLY3208, 1, 1136, 1001, , , , , , , , 4, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 2.3, , 1.7, , , , , , , , , , , , , 0, , , , , , , , 0, , 0, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , D, , , , B, , B, , , , , 89.2, A, ,
,NULL01-01 21:00, 2084, DCNN, DLY3208, 1, 310, 1011, , , , , , , , 8, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , -.6, , -.6, , ,   , , , , , , , , , , 1, , , , , , , , 1, , 1, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , D, , , , D, , D, , , , , 99.3, A, ,
,NULL01-01 21:00, 3197, DCNN, DLY3208, 1, 449, 1001, , , , , , , , 8, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 5.7, , 5.6, , , , , , , , , , , , , 0, , , , , , , , 0, , 0, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , D, , , , B, , B, , , , , 98.5, A, ,
,NULL01-01 21:00, 4967, DCNN, DLY3208, 1, 687, 1001, , , , , , , , 8, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 5.3, , 4.9, , , , , , , , , , , , , 0, , , , , , , , 0, , 0, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , D, , , , B, , B, , , , , 93.6, A, ,
user@HOST:/loc/yearly_files$
```

Comment: Looks like your line endings are `\r\n` instead of just `\n`. I'm wondering if that is the problem?

Comment: @SeanBright you were right. Could you officially reply to the answer so I can accept it please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know what I would say. Someone else can take the credit if they want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: anyone looking to see the issue with smaller sample: `printf 'foo\r\nbaz\r\n' | sed 's/$/X/'`

Comment: You can get rid of the `\r` characters by piping the content through `tr -d '\r'` before sending it to `sed`: `head merged19.csv | tr -d '\r' | sed "s/$/,NULL/"`

Comment: @axiac please don't suggest `tr -d '\r'` or at least add a note that it assumes `\r` is not present anywhere else in the file.. see the duplicate question link I posted for comprehensive take on this topic

Comment: @Sundeep If the file contains `\r` in other context that `\r\n` as EOL then it is probably not a text file. Why would one use `sed` to change it (and why changing it using line-oriented tools, in the first place)?

Comment: @Sundeep is there any tool that is able to read multi-line values from CSV files (assuming the EOL is `\n` and an embedded `\r` is a newline inside a value)?

Comment: @axiac good points.. I'm not an expert in dealing csv.. gawk can handle lot of cases https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk ... if I had to choose, I would go with perl/python with csv modules...

Comment: Ignore all the complicated answers you got (two of them are mine). Use `sed 's/,\r\?$/,A/'`. The extra `\r\?` means an optional `\r` before the end of line. It matches both `\r\n` (Windows new lines) and `\n` (Unix new lines) and it doesn't touch the `\r` that are not present at the end of line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular expression `,$` matches a comma as the last character of the line. If your delimiter is actually a comma plus a space, then you may have an invisible character there which your regex would not match.

In addition, your `NULL` experiment appears to indicate that you have `\r\n` line endings (i.e. your files may have been generated in Windows). You can verify the content of your file using `od` or `hexdump`:

```
$ od -c input.csv | head -18 | tail -4
0000340    ,       ,       ,       ,       D   ,       ,       D   ,
0000360    ,       ,       ,       ,       7   9   ,       A   ,       ,
0000400   \r  \n   1   9   0   0   -   0   1   -   0   1       0   9   :
0000420    0   0   ,       3   1   9   7   ,       D   C   N   N   ,
```

Note the **`\r  \n`**.

You could remove these using `dos2unix` which may be available for your Linux distribution, or a GNU sed script like:

```
$ sed -i 's/\r//' input.csv
```

or a non-GNU sed script run in bash, like this:

```
$ sed -i '' -e $'s/\r//' input.csv
```

or by using the appropriate options in an FTP file transfer. There are some additional options for this [here](https://kb.iu.edu/d/acux).

Once your file is converted, try simply matching the end of the line, if you're pretty sure you've got the right number of delimiters:

```
sed 's/$/A/' input.csv
```

Or even better, if you know that you really want field 103 to be an `A`:

```
awk -F, '{$103="A"} 1' OFS=", "  input.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `.csv` file uses `\r\n` as the EOL character, you can get rid of the `\r` characters by piping the content through `tr -d '\r'` before sending it to `sed`:

```
head merged19.csv | tr -d '\r' | sed 's/$/,NULL/'
```

**Warning:** The `tr` filter removes **all** the `\r` characters present in the file and might break something else in your file structure.
However, if your file contains `\r` not followed by `\n` then either you have a file generated using an ancient version of MacOS (prior to version 10, macOS used to use `\r` as the EOL character) or it is a binary file and using `sed` to handle it is a bad idea anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A PHP solution to replace the Windows end of lines (`\r\n`) with Unix end of lines (`\n`) before passing the input to `sed`:

```
head merged19.csv |\
php -r 'while($line=fgets(STDIN)){echo(str_replace("\r\n","\n",$line));}' |\
sed 's/$/,NULL/'
```

The filter is a small PHP program that reads lines from `stdin`, replaces the `\r\n` combination with `\n` and outputs them to `stdout`.
It doesn't remove the `\r` characters embedded in the text in other combinations; there should be none but this script plays safe and doesn't make this assumption.

The command is wrapped on multiple lines (the backslash, `\`, at the end of line tells `bash` that the command continues on the next line) because the PHP script is quite long for the format used by SO. You can remove the backslash characters (`\`) and write everything on a single line.

Answer (score -1):

You might be experiencing a problem with your terminal display.
Try writing the changes to a separate file and see if it is correct then.

`head merged19.csv | sed "s/$/,NULL/" > testfile`
`cat testfile`
or even try watching it in an editor like:
`nano testfile`